# How to reply to Push Notification like Skype is doing?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, skype

Skype new iOS application allow you to reply to a push notification, how I can do it in my own app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a new functionality in iOS9 called quick reply, it was present for apple messaging app starting from iOS8, but now there is an API available.
For more information check the wwdc2015 video [What's new in notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-720/)
You just need to create a [UIMutableUserNotificationAction](http://fancypixel.github.io/blog/2015/06/11/ios9-notifications-and-text-input/) and add TextInput as its behavior.

Answer (score -1):

you can use "action-loc-key" in notification payload, here I am giving reference to [stackoverflowLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475043/for-push-notifications-how-do-i-add-action-to-alert-view-to-change-views) and [official apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9)

Comment: Not totally correct, from iOS9 you can. It's called quick reply and it works even with the app in bkg.